# Is it possible to access a variable from the enclosing scope inside a callback function in Rust without reference counting or mutexes?

Tags: rust, reference-counting

I am an absolute beginner with rust, so apologies if my question is not phrased in the correct terms, I am happy to provide more clarification if needed.

I am writing a program using `sdl` and `rlua`. This program will load and run a lua script, and provide functions that the script can use. These functions will enable drawing to the SDL renderer.

In order to do that, the rust functions that I register with lua need to have access to the SDL renderer (or `canvas` as it is called by this SDL wrapper).

The only way I have found to access `canvas` in my lua callback is to wrap it in a reference counted mutex. This allows me to maintain multiple mutable references to it, so I can continue to access it in the rest of the enclosing scope. Here is a stripped back version of what I have:

```
extern crate rlua;
extern crate sdl2;

use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let lua = rlua::Lua::new();

    let sdl = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let video = sdl.video().unwrap();

    let window = video.window("", 640, 320).resizable().build().unwrap();

    let canvas = Rc::new(Mutex::new(window.into_canvas().build().unwrap()));
    
    let draw_rect_canvas = canvas.clone();
    let draw_rect = lua
        .create_function_mut(move |_, (x, y, w, h): (i32, i32, u32, u32)| {
            draw_rect_canvas
                .lock()
                .unwrap()
                .draw_rect(sdl2::rect::Rect::new(x, y, w, h))
                .unwrap();
            Ok(())
        })
        .unwrap();

    lua.globals().set("draw_rect", draw_rect).unwrap();

    canvas
        .lock()
        .unwrap()
        .set_draw_color(sdl2::pixels::Color::RGB(0, 0, 0));
}
```

This compiles, and does what I need it to. However, I am left wondering if either the reference counting or mutex are really necessary here, as I assume they introduce a small runtime overhead.

Is there any other way I can tell the compiler the following?

- `canvas` will be present as long as the `draw_rect` lua function is
- The lua function will not be executed at the same time as any other code that accesses `canvas`

Comment: `Mutex` is definitely not necessary, it can be [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).

Comment: Also, `extern crate` is not necessary.

Comment: Also, it can be `create_function()`, no need for `create_function_mut()`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Chayim. From a quick look at the docs `RefCell` is indeed what I should be using instead of `Mutex`.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I had left `create_function_mut` when I was trying out different things to see what works. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference counting and interior mutability look like the correct call here, but you should definitely replace `Mutex` with [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), for better performance and debuggability.

If you have had only one function that needs access to the canvas and no need to access it in the main function, you could've `move`  it directly into the closure without `Rc<RefCell>`, but it looks like this isn't the case.